# Having trouble with json who have image url

Tags: php, json

I tried to make json file to convert my data from database to json and ended up with error (SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data)

when i use a database which not containt img_url it could work but when there is img_url always error.
i tried using .php extension and it works but the img_url is a mess but when i use .json extension it shows the error

this is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT namajurusan, fakultas, deskripsi, img_url FROM tbl_prodi;");

//executing the query 
$stmt->execute();

//binding results to the query 
$stmt->bind_result($namajurusan, $fakultas, $deskripsi, $img_url);

$prodi = array(); 

//traversing through all the result 
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['namajurusan'] = $namajurusan; 
    $temp['fakultas'] = $fakultas; 
    $temp['deskripsi'] = $deskripsi; 
    $temp['img_url'] = $img_url;  
    array_push($prodi, $temp);
}

//displaying the result in json format 
echo json_encode($prodi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode the url using `urlencode` before adding it to the json.

PHP Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Update:

Instead of using `array_push($prodi, $temp);` use `$prodi[] = $temp`.

Comment: which part should i add urlencode? i try change it to $temp['img_url'] = urlencode($img_url); and it doesnt work

Comment: can you var_dump your $prodi variable and display the results? `var_dump($prodi);` before json_encode

Comment: And also stop using array_push and see my updated answer instead,

Comment: okay, i tried but not solve the problem, i gues the problem is the url become like this : http:\/\/ .... something like that and json couldnt accept it. any other advice sir?

Comment: please provide the var_dump as I requested so I will be able to help you further. And did you stop using array_push?

Comment: I did , my code just like this : while($stmt->fetch()){
  $temp = array();
  $temp['namajurusan'] = $namajurusan; 
  $temp['fakultas'] = $fakultas; 
  $temp['deskripsi'] = $deskripsi; 
  $temp['img_url'] = $img_url;  
  $prodi[] = $temp;
 }
 
 var_dump($prodi);
 //displaying the result in json format 
 echo json_encode($prodi);

Comment: show me the output you get when you run the php script

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not sending unparsed strings to your JSON before calling json_encode.
Try to see it using var_dump().

Comment: var_dump($prodi) before json_encode.
comment the line echo json_encode($prodi); to see the result.
Then come back here and post what you got. Probably you are trying to parse an invalid string.